# Can't send my XTZ from any wallet

Tags: xtz

i created a wallet on atomicwallet and sent my xtz from an exchange. 
Problem is I can't send from atomic, transaction fails, and I tried to load my private key into other wallets, it doesnt work either.
 it doesn't work on tezbox either, or any wallet I tried. Transaction fails evert time,like if the balance was empty.
Please help !

Comment: what error message do you get ? please put screenshot if possible.